# How to play a file by id in nyxmms2

Tags: audio, playback

In nyxmms2 when I do a search, it returns a list of files along with their ids. All I seem to be able to do with that search is add everything that's found with the add command using the same arguments for the search.

What if I just wanted to add some of the files found in that search? I noticed that there are ids listed for each song. Is there a way I can specify only certain songs by their ids?

Also, what if instead of adding to the playlist I wanted to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a song by ID:

```
nyxmms2 add -t id:111
```

Clear the playlist:

```
nyxmms2 clear
```